# I want to apply a background image to the body of only one component

Tags: css, reactjs

I am very new to React, so apologies for the mistakes in advance.

In my React app, say I have 2 components and as the CSS styles are global, it picks up CSS styles from all the files.

However, I wish to add a full background image to one of the components which I was able to achieve by using this code in my CSS file:

```
body {
  background-image: url("../image.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

The problem is that the same image is also being applied to another component. I read a few answers and found that I can use ComponentDidMount hook and add the image to the body tag there. I tried that, but it doesn't show anything.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('../image.jpg')";
    document.body.style.backgroundPosition = "center";
    document.body.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
    document.body.style.backgroundSize = "cover";
  }
```

**EDIT**

I realized I had the wrong wording for the question. What I mean to say is that I have two pages in React. For one of the pages, I want a full background image. However, because CSS styles are global, the background image is getting applied to all the pages.

Comment: What do you mean the "body" of a component? In your CSS "body" refers to the `<body/>` HTML tag, there's only one per page. It doesn't refer to a specific component

Comment: Did you meant to add background to body, or background to specific component. Eg. background to `About component` or `footer component`

Comment: Please post the code for your component and how it is being rendered. What is it trying to do? What is the desired behavior? There is only one instance of the `body` tag in the DOM tree. So how do two instances render the same image on the body tag?

Comment: I have edited the summary for clarity. Sorry for the incorrect wording.

Comment: ok, when you say `CSS styles are global` what do you mean? Each component should localize the styling to itself. I would avoid setting a bg image on the body tag, but rather let your component render an element that is `position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;` with a `z-index: 0` so its underneath the normal content or something to that effect. If you'd like to post a codesandbox or something replicating the issue i'd be happy to help you fix it. hard to help though with the current information

Comment: @RishabGupta [**like this**](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-oxrwj). You can avoid trying to make changes with global elements which will end up being buggy anyways. Let the component deal with its own styles so those are cleaned up when it unmounts

Answer (score 0):

You can use inline styling or specific styling by assigning a specific class or ID to the top element of one component.

INLINE STYLING Example:

```js
// If Background variable has url to the background image.
const style = {
  backgroundImage: `url(${Background})`
}


// in component use that inline style

return (
<div style={style}></div>
);
```

IF YOU WANT TO WORK with body only...
then add a class to body on component A mount and remove the class on component B mount. And attach the background property to the class.

Comment: this will only apply the image to that div. I want the image to cover the complete page which I was only able to achieve by using it in a body tag.

Comment: why not just position the element to be the size of the whole page?

Comment: There can only be one body element for a DOM. you can't have multiple body elements for multiple components. As @JohnRuddell suggested you can scale your component's top level element to fit your needs.

Comment: another way out is you can add a class to body on component A mount and remove the class on component B mount. and attach the background property to the class.

Answer (score 0):

A component usually return some jsx and in most cases a `div`. In other to apply a css to a single component I mean the jsx the component is rendering. you should define a css class, that apply a background image to the div the component is rendering and make the height of the `div` the window height. you can do this via inline css all

```js
   

 const MainDiv =()=>(
    <div classname="testClass">
        This will show background image in the covering the entire body
        //Other content of your page can be added here like the rest of your page contents
       <header>
          This is my blog post
       </header>
       <nav>
          this is my navbar
       </nav>
    </div>
);
ReactDOM.render(<MainDiv />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
    .testClass{
    backgroundImage :"url('../image.jpg')";
    backgroundPosition :"center";
    backgroundRepeat : "no-repeat";
    background-size : "cover";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh
}
```